# Getting error while connecting firebase with chrome extension (locally)

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension

I have tried everything I could find on the internet to enable firebase in my chrome extension, but nothing seems to be working. I couldn't get the firebase objects.

The errors that I am facing right now:

Error 1: Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at firebase.js:11

[Image Reference Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px7pL.png)

**manifest.js**

Here is the manifest.json file.

```js
    {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name": "Chrome Proxy",
        "permissions": [
            "proxy",
            "tabs",
            "unlimitedStorage",
            "storage",
            "<all_urls>",
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking"
        ],
        "browser_action": {
            "default_popup": "home.html",
            "default_icon": "logo.png"
        },
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
        "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ 
         https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
    }
```

**home.html**

Here is the home.html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.7/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.7/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.7/firebase-database.js"></script>
    
    <script type="module" src="firebase.js"></script>
    <title>CPM Extension</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="hasham">Hasham Here!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**firebase.js**

Here is the firebase.js file.

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "my_api_key",
    authDomain: "my_auth_name",
    databaseURL: "my_database_url",
    projectId: "my_project_id",
    storageBucket: "my_storage_bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "my_messaginge_sender_id",
    appId: "my_app_id"
}

firebase.initializeApp( firebaseConfig )
console.log(firebase)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about your implementation and I found a quick way you could achieve what you want. In short, you will need to install webpack, which is a module bundler (it means that its main purpose is to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser). If you have npm already set up, you can execute this command in your project:

```
npm install webpack
```

If you haven't set up npm yet, there are plenty of tutorials online (and if you don't understand, feel free to ask me ;)
After you have done that you can proceed to set up firebase. You will need to run another command:

```
npm install firebase
```

Continuing the setup of webpack, you will need to create a webpack.config.js file and there set the entry and the output. Again, you can find plenty of tutorials online, but here's a quick example implementation:

webpack.config.js:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        main: './src/main'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        overlay: true,
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'manifest.json', to: 'manifest.json' },
            ],
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'images', to: 'images' },
            ],
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'popup.html', to: 'popup.html' },
            ],
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],


};
```

Once you've done that, in your entry file (the entry point), you can import firebase and set it up:

main.js

```
 import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    
// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Next, you will set the output file as a source in your html popup (in this case it will be 'main.budle.js'). When you run `npm start`, webpack will create another folder (the 'dist' folder). This folder is the chrome exstension with firebase set up!

I hope I was able to answer your question! If you need any help, feel free to comment and ask questions.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @arslan-ali, thanks for your suggestion I was able to do what I wanted, I just had to look up the webpack documentation and a tutorial for node js and webpack and finally I was able to handle the firebase. Moreover, I would like to include that if you're using firebase then you must need to use **async await** to handle the responses in that case add `experiments: {topLevelAwait: true}` in **webpack.config.js** file. Best Regards.