# Hello, how can I open a popup window with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My problem is this, I want to authenticate and on the endpoint I have a re-direct. The issue was using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() . And it works correctly for me, the problem is that it doesn't work with the Opera browser, for example. (Having support...) But if you open a window. Something like this... chrome.tabs.create({url : authUrl});

The question here opens a new window. And the question that opens a pop-up window something that I can manipulate later.

Because after I redirect it I have to grab that token and send it to the extension. And close that popup.

And I don't know how to do it. Already the API of chrome.
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() does it all by itself.

The question is how can I do it without using that.

Comment: Use [webext-launch-web-auth-flow](https://github.com/eight04/webext-launch-web-auth-flow).

Comment: Do you have an example? Thanks!

Comment: The link I gave contains the info and an example.

Comment: I have a doubt I call it like that. I don't use the requires, right? Because it will give me an error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you asked. Do you mean that you can't import this package because it would throw an error? In that case you can use webpack (or any other module bundler) to import external packages easily.

Comment: Sure, the error in the extension tells me Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

Comment: In that case you should use webpack. I have already written an SO answer on that [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71277985/getting-error-while-connecting-firebase-with-chrome-extension-locally/71280872#71280872). Instead of installing firebase you should install webext-launch-web-auth-flow

Comment: Simply download the script from unpkg, which is linked in the description, no need to require anything. Then call webextLaunchWebAuthFlow() with your parameters.

Comment: And I call it in the background right and/or content script?